# Install Mapnik on Centos 7: ICU C++ Library Not Found

Tags: centos, icu, centos7, mapnik

**Problem/Introduction:**

I'm trying to install *Mapnik* on *Centos 7*. I've had about a year UNIX experience in the professional environment, but I am still very much a beginner. I've compiled and installed boost which to my knowledge comes with ICU C++ Libraries. Unfortunately when I run *./configure* for Mapnik installation I get the following error:

```
Exiting... the following required dependencies were not found:
- icuuc (ICU C++ library | configure with ICU_LIBS & ICU_INCLUDES or    use ICU_LIB_NAME to specify custom lib name  | more info: http://site.icu-project.org/)
```

How do I install this library? I can't find any good internet resources, or maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe both boost and ICU are available as packages for CentOS 7. Is there a reason you aren't using those?

Comment: That actually fixed my problem, I installed boost from source originally because I didn't know it was a package. I install boost as a package and now the install runs smoothly, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

1. yum install freetype-devel libtool-ltdl-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel gcc-c++ libicu-devel python-devel bzip2-devel boost libwebp-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel libpng-devel sqlite-devel gdal-devel gdal-python
2. wget https://mapnik.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/v3.0.10/mapnik-v3.0.10.tar.bz2
3. tar -xf ./mapnik-v3.0.10.tar.bz2
4. cd ./mapnik-v3.0.10/
5. ./configure
6. make && make install

Answer (score -1):

- Mapnik v3.0.10 needs Boost of minimum version **v1.56**
- CentOS 7 is shipped with version **v1.53**